# на русском языке или русским языком?

Tags: падежи

работа написана на грамотном русском языке
или
работа написана грамотным русским языком?

Answer (score 1):

*1. Работа написана на русском языке.*

*2. Работа написана грамотным языком.*

Думаю, что, прочитав эти два примера, Вы сами выберете правильный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Обе формы возможны, то есть допускается наличие  прилагательного в этих выражениях. Обычно в этом случае описываются ситуации, где важно указать уровень владения языком, в том числе подчеркнуть  грамотность письменной речи.

В то же время  фраза "Работа должна быть написана **грамотным русским языком**" в большей степени  соответствует **деловому стилю**, так как здесь используется **творительный (инструментальный) падеж**. (Сущ. в Т.п. придает действию известный вид, форму, образ).

Примеры

1) Хотя как было не понять чётких вопросов, заданных ей на простом русском языке? Юсупов― один из лучших комиков ― очень смешно и обаятельно говорил на нарочито неправильном русском языке. Сиреневый, провалившись в кадку, на чистом русском языке, без признаков какого-либо акцента, вскричал...

2) Говорил Апенушкин чистым, грамотным русским языком, без примеси местных словечек. Он говорил ломаным русским языком, но все его отлично понимали.

Comment: А если учесть, что это должен быть официально-деловой стиль?

Comment: Есть и неформальное выражение: "Я тебе русским языком говорю!" Скорее, вариант "на" соответствует выбору одного из языков, а творительный падеж делает акцент на особенностях способа выражения или стиля в рамках языка (в примере выше - смысловой акцент на "понятном" собеседнику способе донести мысль).

Comment: Да, с Т.п. всё более или менее понятно. Аlex-ander, а как вы думаете, откуда в сочетании "говорить/писать на русском языке" предложный падеж с предлогом НА.? Что он означает?

Comment: Возможно, "на русском языке" означает "делать это, находясь в пределах пространства, или на территории русского языка". Напр. полиглоты говорят, что переключаются между сформированными у себя в мозгу центрами отдельных языков.

Comment: А мне кажется близким выражение " говорить на базе (на основе) русского языка" (всё равно как играть на инструменте), используя этот базис для формирования речи.